# why LCIS should be solved with dynamic programming design

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization

I am reading the book "Introduction to Algorithm" and especially in the dynamic programming chapter i've learned these notes :

```
    The second ingredient that an optimization problem must have for 
    dynamic programming to apply is that the space of subproblems must 
    be “small” in the sense that a recursive algorithm for the problem
    solves the same subproblems over and over, rather than always generating 
    new subproblems
```

when i apply the dynamic programming design on the problem LCIS "Longest Increasing Common Subsequence " , I didn't figure out where is the overlapping of subproblems , (i understand that a brute force algorithm costs O(N * 2^m))

Comment: Take a few examples, break down the problem to a few subproblems of depth 1-2, and please add it to the question

Comment: There's an art to setting up a problem formulation in such a way that it has a "small" space of subproblems.